# Calculate the probability of obtaining Spades, Hearts and Clubs in R in that order

Tags: r, r-markdown, probability

I'm struggling with this, can anyone help me plz?
My current code is

```
N <- probspace(urnsamples(pcartas, 3,replace=FALSE, ordered=TRUE))
CDE <- intersect(subset(N, (N$outcomes[[]][[2]][1] == "Spade")), 
      subset(N, (N$outcomes[[]][[2]][2] == "Heart")), subset(N, (N$outcomes[[]][[2]][3] == "Club"))) 
pcorazones_diamantes_espadas <- Prob(CDE)
```

But it is not working.
Thank you very much

Comment: Please show a small reprodcuible example.  I see some strange indexing `N$outcomes[[]][[2]][1]`  what is `[[]]`.  Is that part of the package.  Not sure without the package info andd reproducble example

Comment: Where do `probspace` and `urnsamples` come from? [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making a question that's easier to answer

Comment: Why not just  `13/52 * 13/51 * 13/50` (= 0.01656862745)

Comment: I must use r prob functions, to show that I know how they work but thanks

Comment: From one deck of cards? From an urn containing 10 spades, 9 hearts, and 6 clubs?

Comment: What is `pcartas`? Can you `dput` this in your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think your `pcartas` object should be a simple vector, not a data frame. Otherwise you'll have difficulties with extracting elements of a list.

Clear the R workspace, install the **prob** package and load it.

```
rm(list=ls())
install.packages("prob")
library(prob)
```

Create the sample space.

```
pcartas <- cards()$suit
```

You'll see that this is a factor vector. I'm going to convert this to a character vector because the `urnsamples` function converts the labels into their numeric codes, which makes it difficult when you want to calculate the probabilities. You'll see the problem if you don't do this next step.

```
pcartas <- unclass(as.character(pcartas))
```

Sample without replacement from this sample space and convert to a probability space (your first line of code above):

```
L <- urnsamples(pcartas, size=3, replace=FALSE, ordered=TRUE);
N <- probspace(L);
```

Calculate the probability of any event. For example, the probability of obtaining a "Spade" on the first card is:

```
Prob(N, X1=="Spade")  # Answer=0.25 or 13/52
```

And the probability of obtaining a spade on the first card and a heart on the second is:

```
Prob(N, X1=="Spade" & X2=="Heart")  # Answer=0.0637 or 13/52 * 13/51
```

And finally, the probability of obtaining a spade on the first card and a heart on the second card and a club on the third is:

```
Prob(N, X1=="Spade" & X2=="Heart" & X3=="Club") # Answer=0.016568 or 13/52 * 13/51 * 13/50
```

If you didn't convert the sample space object to a character vector, then you would have to use the numeric codes to get the probabilities:

```
Prob(N, X1==1 & X2==2 & X3==3)
```